# Production issues - disable ASP.NET debugging, restrict access to directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I deployed my latest web site to production environment, now client found that the following issues on my deployment. and that are to be fixed.

I just need some clarification from you all on the following

1. disable ASP.NET debugging

I already set compilation debug="false" in the web.config, is there anything that to be done apart from this?

1. restrict access to directory

any idea on defining access rights for users?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
<compilation 
    debug="false"
/>
```

on your web.config

[HOW TO: Disable Debugging for ASP.NET Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815157)

[ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx)

this will display the exact error that user gets.

And if your application has an download.upload file into a folder you need to

Share Folder name “YourFileFolder” and add ‘Network Service’ account  having read/write permission

Regards

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration setting in machine.config(only) called:

```
      <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <deployment retail="true"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

This parameter will automatically turn off [debugging features](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx)(tracing,compilation,...).

For your security rights, give only access on your directory to the iis pool user.

To disable Browsing in IIS7 add this to your web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
     <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: It depends. Are you running IIS7 or IIS6? usually, for IIS6 it's the network service account which runs the pool. For IIS7, by default a user with the name of the pool runs the pool. But the best practice is to create a user specific to your apps with its rights locked down to the strict minimum.

Comment: The IIS_IUSRS is a special group. By default, every apppool account belongs to this group. So, giving rights to this group on your application folders will work. But the best practice is still to create a unique account for your pool. See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis/

Comment: 1. Is it machine.config or web.config? in the article it is machine.config
2. For example if do not create separate account for my app pool and if I still use IIS_IUSRS, what permission I need to give in order to disable directory browsing?
Thanks

Comment: You can put it either in machine.config or either in web.config. Directory browsing is done at IIS level, not file level. When you go to IIS 7 console, go to your web site and in the IIS section(second line) there is a property called Directory Browsing. It's available also in IIS 6.

Comment: I can find Directory Browsing in IIS, may I know how to configure in order to disable directory browsing

Comment: It can only be added into machine.config. It is invalid in web.config!

Answer (score 0):

In my case (error:

> debugging should be disabled in the web.config file

) i basically turned web.config to :

```
   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

note:I use Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Are you sure it's not `debug="false"`?

Comment: it was 'false' and i was getting this "the page cannot be run in debug mode because debugging is not enabled in the web.config file" error than i have changed it to 'true' note:i'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: Then this is not an answer to this question.

Comment: i couldn't find the right answer and i'm hoping this will help people with trying to struggle who are in my case.